Can someone create Myers-Briggs as a synonym for MBTI?
Apparently I need to answer more questions about that before I can even suggest the tag using the SE interface (which is pretty dumb if you ask me.)
So can someone with the required privileges create myers-briggs  as synonym for mbti? It seems uncontroversial to me.
Note that simply typing Myers in the tag box (when editing questions) does not search for (i.e. pop up) MBTI. The search apparently doesn't go as deep as using the tag description.
There was one recent questions here that was tagged with pretty much everything every personality-related tag, except the most focused one (which was MBTI). I suspect it's because the acronym doesn't show up in the question, only the spelled-out name does.

what does the TI stand for then?

@AliceD: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  You could of course create myers-briggs-type-Indicator as the alias, but I'm not seeing how it would make a difference from I proposed.

I've gone ahead and created this synonym - my hope is that by making the tag easier to find, users might read the tag description about MBTI being "largely debunked by science."  Thanks for the good suggestion @Fizz.

@ArnonWeinberg has addressed this:

I've gone ahead and created this synonym - my hope is that by making the tag easier to find, users might read the tag description about MBTI being "largely debunked by science." Thanks for the good suggestion @Fizz.

I therefore marked this question as status-completed.


Note that simply typing Myers in the tag box (when editing questions) does not search for (i.e. pop up) MBTI. The search apparently doesn't go as deep as using the tag description

The answer to this problem would be to alter the mbti to myers-briggs-type-indicator-mbti or add myers-briggs-type-indicator as the synonym.  That way myers, briggs and mbti can be searched for, and the full acronym is covered.
